# Swift 4: cast issue with Generics

Tags: swift, swift4, xcode9

I'm new to Swift, after many years as an Objective-C developer. I'm struggling to understand how type casting works with generics.

I have two functions that are doing object mapping with Alamofire + Codable and Alamofire + ObjectMapper. Something like this:

---

```
public func performRestOperationWithDecodable<ResponseClass: Decodable>(
    _ restOperationType: NetworkServiceRestOperationType,
    pathUrl: URLConvertible,
    parameters: Parameters,
    encoding: ParameterEncoding,
    savedAuthType: NetworkServiceAuthType,
    activityIndicator: ActivityIndicatorProtocol?,
    successBlock: @escaping (_ responseObject: DataResponse<ResponseClass>) -> Void,
    errorBlock:@escaping (_ error: Error, _ validResponse: Bool) -> Void) {

    let restConfiguration = self.setupRestOperation(
        savedAuthType: savedAuthType,
        pathUrl: pathUrl,
        activityIndicator: activityIndicator)

    Alamofire
        .request(
            restConfiguration.url,
            method: .get,
            parameters: parameters,
            encoding: encoding,
            headers: restConfiguration.headers)
        .validate(
            contentType: Constants.Network.DefaultValidContentTypeArray)
        .responseDecodableObject(
            queue: self.dispatchQueue,
            keyPath: nil,
            decoder: JSONDecoder(),
            completionHandler: { (responseObject: DataResponse<ResponseClass>) in
                self.completionRestOperation(
                    responseObject: responseObject,
                    activityIndicator: activityIndicator,
                    successBlock: successBlock,
                    errorBlock: errorBlock)
            })
}
```

---

---

```
public func performRestOperationWithObjectMapper<ResponseClass: BaseMappable>(
    _ restOperationType: NetworkServiceRestOperationType,
    pathUrl: URLConvertible,
    parameters: Parameters,
    encoding: ParameterEncoding,
    savedAuthType: NetworkServiceAuthType,
    activityIndicator: ActivityIndicatorProtocol?,
    successBlock: @escaping (_ responseObject: DataResponse<ResponseClass>) -> Void,
    errorBlock: @escaping (_ error: Error, _ validResponse: Bool) -> Void) {

    let restConfiguration = self.setupRestOperation(
        savedAuthType: savedAuthType,
        pathUrl: pathUrl,
        activityIndicator: activityIndicator)

    Alamofire
        .request(
            restConfiguration.url,
            method: .get,
            parameters: parameters,
            encoding: encoding,
            headers: restConfiguration.headers)
        .validate(
            contentType: Constants.Network.DefaultValidContentTypeArray)
        .responseObject(
            queue: self.dispatchQueue,
            keyPath: nil,
            mapToObject: nil,
            context: nil,
            completionHandler: { (responseObject: DataResponse<ResponseClass>) in
                self.completionRestOperation(
                    responseObject: responseObject,
                    activityIndicator: activityIndicator,
                    successBlock: successBlock,
                    errorBlock: errorBlock)
            })
}
```

---

Each function has a generic type that conform to appropriate protocol needed by the mapper used (Decodable for Codable, Mappable for ObjectMapper). And these funcion compliles and worked as expected.
Now I'm trying to write a third function that have a third Generics type, but without conforming to any protocol, and forcing cast to the appropriate generics depending on a configuration parameter. Something like that:

---

```
public func performRestOperation<ResponseMappedClass :AnyObject>(
    _ restOperationType: NetworkServiceRestOperationType,
    pathUrl: URLConvertible,
    parameters: Parameters = [:],
    encoding: ParameterEncoding = URLEncoding.queryString,
    savedAuthType: NetworkServiceAuthType,
    activityIndicator: ActivityIndicatorProtocol?,
    successBlock: @escaping (_ responseObject: ResponseMappedClass) -> Void,
    errorBlock: @escaping (_ error: Error, _ validResponse: Bool) -> Void) {

    if self.canDoRestOperation(errorBlock: errorBlock) != true {
        return
    }

    switch self.mappingType {
        case .Codable:
            self.performRestOperationWithDecodable(
                restOperationType,
                pathUrl: pathUrl,
                parameters: parameters,
                encoding: encoding,
                savedAuthType: savedAuthType,
                activityIndicator: activityIndicator,
                successBlock: { (responseObject: DataResponse<ResponseMappedClass>) in
                    let response: ResponseMappedClass = responseObject.result.value!
                    successBlock(response)
                } as! (DataResponse<ResponseMappedClass & Decodable>) -> Void,
                errorBlock: { (error: Error, validResponse: Bool) in
                    errorBlock(error, validResponse)
                })

        case .ObjectMapper:
            // TODO

            break
    }
}
```

---

With the instruction: `as! (DataResponse<ResponseMappedClass & Decodable>) -> Void`, I'm trying to cast from the "generic" class type `ResponseMappedClass` to the same class, but with `Codable` support.
But that instruction doesn't compile:

> Non-protocol, non-class type 'ResponseMappedClass' cannot be used
>   within a protocol-constrained type

After all that process, the various generics will represent the same class, for example `SomeModelObject`, that implements `Codable`, `Mappable` or maybe something else in future, so the usual type substitution at compile time, have to work anyway.

Any suggestions? Is it totally impossible to do in Swift?

Comment: Perhaps I'm just dense, but I'm not understanding what you're trying to do or why. Maybe you could explain what you were previously doing in Objective-C that you cannot do in Swift?

Comment: If you could cut down these examples so they contain less irrelevant information and dependencies on other code we can't see, that would be really helpful. A more abstract answer would be preferable.

Comment: Holy parameters batman... General tip when dealing with Swift: never force cast anything unless the desired behavior is for your app to crash. Regardless, there's so much noise in your question I'm not even sure what you're trying to do 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to use a generic types in combination with protocols. The compiler doesn't consider them as class or protocol type. One more thing is wrong with your code, you are using `self.mappingType` to decide is it a `Decodable` or `Mapable` type. What if `self.mappingType == .Codable`, but `ResponseMappedClass` doesn't confirm to `Decodable` protocol? What I can suggest to you is function overloading. Create 3 functions:

```
    public func performRestOperation<ResponseMappedClass: AnyObject>(...) where ResponseMappedClass: Decodable {

    }

    public func performRestOperation<ResponseMappedClass: AnyObject>(...) where ResponseMappedClass: BaseMappable {

    }

    public func performRestOperation<ResponseMappedClass: AnyObject>(...) {   

    }
```

in the last one just throw an error. The right funcion will be called depending on the generic parameter type.

Answer (score 0):

```
(DataResponse<ResponseMappedClass & Decodable>)
```

What I think you are doing wrong is that `ResponseMappedClass`is a **class** and `Decodable` on the other hand is a **protocol**. And you can not cast a class & protocol type together.

So, the error is exactly as it says.

### Non-protocol, non-class type 'ResponseMappedClass' cannot be used within a protocol-constrained type

Something like this will work as both the types are protocol.

```
as! (DataResponse<Codable & Decodable>) -> Void
```